# 'The OData request is not supported' error while updating contacts using outlook rest api

Tags: python, python-requests, exchangewebservices, contacts, office365api

I am trying to update a contact in exchange online using outlook rest
API.  I am able to create a contact using post. I have also tested
patch which is working fine. That said, when I am sending a`PUT` request it's not working.

So here is my code:

```
def update_contacts():
    # / ContactsFolders/{folder_id}/contacts
    contact_id = "AAMkADAzNTg5ZjFmLWI2OTItNDFiOC1iNzg5LTNmOTJmOGUxYmUxNwBGAAAAAABMzp004WaZQqK4q_HRlSK9BwAqlNNaGOnjR7gnbsbOcpkFAAJm6kCDAAAqlNNaGOnjR7gnbsbOcpkFAAJm6m_3AAA="
    url = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/users('{email_id}')/contacts/{contact_id}"
    #data = {"GivenName": "C1_Updated_put", "DisplayName": "MyRestApiContactFolder1"}
    data =  {
            "Categories": [],
            "Birthday": None,
            "FileAs": "",
            "DisplayName": "MyRestApiContactFolder1",
            "GivenName": "C1_Using_Put",
            "Initials": None,
            "MiddleName": None,
            "NickName": None,
            "Surname": None,
            "Title": None,
            "YomiGivenName": None,
            "YomiSurname": None,
            "YomiCompanyName": None,
            "Generation": None,
            "ImAddresses": [],
            "JobTitle": None,
            "CompanyName": None,
            "Department": None,
            "OfficeLocation": None,
            "Profession": None,
            "BusinessHomePage": None,
            "AssistantName": None,
            "Manager": None,
            "HomePhones": [],
            "MobilePhone1": None,
            "BusinessPhones": [],
            "SpouseName": None,
            "PersonalNotes": "",
            "Children": [],
            "EmailAddresses": [],
            "HomeAddress": {
                "Type": "Unknown"
            },
            "BusinessAddress": {
                "Type": "Unknown"
            },
            "OtherAddress": {
                "Type": "Unknown"
            }
        }
    req = url.format(email_id=email_id, contact_id=contact_id)
    resp = requests.put(url=req, json=data, headers=HEADERS)
    #print(HEADERS)
    print(resp)
    resp = resp.json()
    print(resp)
```

Here is my header for the request-

```
def set_headers():
    global HEADERS
    token_resp = get_token(email_id).json()
    access_token = token_resp.get('access_token')
    HEADERS['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+ access_token
    HEADERS["content-type"] = "application/json"
    HEADERS['accept'] =  "application/json"
    HEADERS['X-AnchorMailbox'] = email_id
    #print(HEADERS)
```

This is the `response(405)` using the print statements:

```
<Response [405]> {u'error': {u'message': u'The OData request is not
supported.', u'code': u'ErrorInvalidRequest'}}
```

Comment: Are you sure that server accepts `PUT` requests? It probably doesn't and hence your error.

Answer (score 0):

According to their docs you need to use PATCH method to update: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/contact-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).